# c# Threads and Thread.Join

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a list of 10 items that I need to process, with each item using a separate thread. Should the code be like this:

```
foreach (Item item in items)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ProcessItem(item);
    });
    t.Start();
}
```

I would also need to pause the thread for (1 second minus the time taken to execute the thread). Should I use Thread.Sleep in this case?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this code? Are experiencing any issues? And yes, `Thread.Sleep()` — you could have read the MSDN…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind skipping the manual handling of Threads, the following line should do exactly what you want:

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, ProcessItem);
```

Or sleeping before processing each (although that does not make much sense):

```
Parallel.ForEach(items, item => { Thread.Sleep(1000); ProcessItem(item); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use `Thread.Join` to wait for other threads to finish their work.

`Thread.Sleep` will essentially wait for the specified number of **milli-seconds**

`Thread.Sleep` indeed has side-effects and is not recommended.

Some points to be noted in your context:

1. What if there are no more threads available (if the number of `items` increases ?)
2. Does the threads access some shared resources ?

Check out the `ThreadPooling` and `thread-safe` operations too.

Comment: Sleep() has side-effects?

Comment: @MartinJames: I meant in the context, that `sleep()` could block the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

The code for starting the threads looks fine.

You will have to use `Thread.Sleep(duration in milliseconds)` for making the thread to pause for duration amount of time.

`Join` will halt the current thread until the thread on which you join does not complete its processing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if, for some reason, you don't want to use the `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
int count = 0;
foreach (Item item in items)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ProcessItem(item);
    });
    t.Start();
    threads[count++]=t;
}
for (int i=0;i<10;++i)
    threads[i].Join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.Sleep`.

[Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx) and [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) are different things.

`Thread.Sleep` blocks (stops) the current thread for a certain time.

`Thread.Join` blocks (stops) the current thread until the one which `Join` was called finishes.

---

Also, consider using [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) as @nvoigt suggested.